# How to refresh the Odometer's index by Java code

Tags: java

I'm trying to display the mileage of a car day by day base on the indexes from the Odometer. However, I confused how to refresh these indexes, because the number increase and bigger and bigger depend on how long the car passed. So can someone suggest me good solution for this problem, I get stuck now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is unclear. What is the problem with the number getting bigger?

Comment: this mean that the mileages you see currently are equal the sum of the indexes that calculated from yesterday back to the first day.

Comment: Yes, but why is that a problem?

Comment: For example: when you check the Odometer on Saturday(if it start from the Monday) you see the number is 100 km, but I want to check how long the car travelled on Friday (ex: if it passed 20km). I represent the data on line chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The milage for a day is:

```
(Odometer reading today) - (odometer reading yesterday)
```

**Edit:**

The milage for an hour is:

```
(Odometer reading today) - (odometer reading yesterday)
```

If your readings aren't performed at even intervals you can display a "miles per xxx" value:

```
((Odometer reading at time = t2) - (odometer reading at time = t1)) / (t2 - t1)
```

This is the average speed of the car in the time interval. If you express the time in days you get miles per day. If you convert the time interval to hours you get miles per hour.

Comment: Imagine the milage would be reset to 0 every day. Would be heaven for car dealers ("this 16 year old car's only run 5 miles") ;)

Comment: @Klas Lindbäck I want to display the data on line chart that show the index in hour and minute. I understand your idea but I found hard to represent it by Java code...